# How do I prove $\int \phi_{ab}dG=\int_a^b G(x)dx$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability-distributions

Consider $\phi_{ab}(x)=b-a\:\:(x<a)$

$=b-x\:\:(a\leqslant x\leqslant b)$

$=0 \:\:(x>b)$

How do I prove the following condition.

$\int_\mathbb{R} \phi_{ab}dG=\int_a^b G(x)dx$

G is a distribution function therefore ($0\leqslant G\leqslant1$). I have tried integration by parts but it did not yield any convincing result.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Give more details about G and $\phi $ for $x \geq a$

Comment: Also please clarify the bounds on the first of your two integrals

Comment: @Veliko Is it more clear now?

Comment: @fractal1729  Is it more clear now?

Comment: @PedroGomes, yes, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all 
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \phi_{ab}\, \mathrm{d}G = \int_{-\infty}^b \phi_{ab}\,\,\mathrm{d}G.
$$
Supposing we can integrate by parts we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^b \phi_{ab}\,\,\mathrm{d}G = \phi_{ab}G\big|_{-\infty}^{b} - \int_{-\infty}^b G\,\,\mathrm{d}\phi_{ab}.
$$
Now for the first part we actually have
$$
\phi_{ab}G\big|_{-\infty}^{b} = \phi_{ab}(b)G(b) - \lim\limits_{t\to -\infty}\phi_{ab}(t)G(t) = 0\times G(b) - (b-a)0 = 0.
$$
Note: By definition $\lim\limits_{t\to-\infty}G(t) = 0$.

For the second part we make a split since $\mathrm{d}\phi_{ab} = 0$ for $x <a$ and finally obtain
$$
\int_\mathbb{R} \phi_{ab}\, \mathrm{d}G = 0 -\int_{-\infty}^b G\,\,\mathrm{d}\phi_{ab} = -\int_{a}^b G(x)(-1)\mathrm{d}x -\int_{-\infty}^a G(x)\times 0 \,\mathrm{d}x = \int_a^bG(x)dx.
$$

Comment: Why do you have $\int_{-\infty}^a G(x)\times 0 \,\mathrm{d}x$? Where does the 0 come from? I thought $\phi_{ab}(x)\:\:\text{for}\:\:x<0$ was equal to $b-a$ and not to 0. Anyway nice job!

Comment: @PedroGomes you have $\mathrm{d}\phi_{ab} = 0$ for $x \in (-\infty; a)$ since $\phi_{ab} = Const$ in that interval. From this comes the $\times 0$. You are forgetting to take a derivative...